# How to create fake nodes

Tags: nodes, theming

I would like to know how to fake a node in Drupal. I have a table with drawings. The drawings have non unique names. For each drawing I want to be able to create a page using the unique id of the drawing:

like so: http://mysite.com/drawing/100

I don't want to create nodes for each drawing but still be able to have a theme template to show the contents of the drawing record.

How do I do that. And if this is possible how do I access the drawing number in my template page?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't need drawings on the page, the question is how to have a themed node for each drawing without actually creating the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is rather basic module development. Setting up a page that takes an argument.

Check out the [Example module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), and more specifically the [page_example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/page_example!page_example.module/7) module and `page_example_arguments()`. That contains the base of what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the example. What I don't see in the example is where the template file comes in. I want a template like page--drawing.tpl.php to handle the page generation.

Comment: To have a template generate my content for each drawing item, I used the theme_render_template function. Maybe this is also possible using a render array as done in the examples (referenced by enzipher), but I don't know how.

So far theme_render_template does what I want.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a tpl.php file when you're generating output in a custom module. You can also generate a [render array](http://drupal.org/node/930760) containing html in your menu callback. If you do want to use template files, implement [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) in your module and add a #theme property to your render array (see also http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/render_example%21render_example.module/group/render_example/7).

Comment: Thanks. I do want to use a template file because the html will be complex and I think it will be easier and cleaner to use a template file.

Comment: Can you tell me how to specifiy the template file in hook_theme?